# PMT formula Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I took a loan from the bank in the amount of 200,000 USD. The loan is for 17 years.
I repay the loan through regular payments every month. The monthly interest rate on the loan is 0.4%.
At the end of the loan period, in addition to the last payment, I pay an additional  10,000 USD.
What is the regular monthly payment I will make each month?

Can you explain me please how to use this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are paying the last 10k at the end, that is effectively the Future Value of the loan when it terminates. So you can enter that as the fv in the PMT function:

```
=PMT(0.004,17*12,-200000,10000)
```

or 1404.25

> Note that the signs of the Pv and Fv must be opposite in this case. So
> if you want to show your PMT as a negative value, you must use +200000
> and -10000.